# Morris chart set y axis value

Tags: morris.js

I am trying to display a chart for app ranking using morris.js. The ranks will be between 1 to 50. So there will not be 0 rank. I want the max y axis value to be 1, not 0. Please review the images. How can i configure this? Please help.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [perk.com](http://s3-rtb-cdn2.perk.com/creatives/Screenshot_1.png))</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ymin (or ymax, if you invert the scale).

http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/lines.html